# How to parse value inside array from many json key

Tags: node.js, json, typescript

I'm have problem to get value from first key and last key of by request body.

This is my request body:

```
{
    "A": [
        {
            "filter": [
                {"a": "a"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "group": [
                {"a": "a"}
            ]
        }
    ],
    "B": [
        {
            "filter": [
                {"a": "a"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "group": [
                {"a": "a"}  
            ]
        }
    ], ...
}
```

How to get value json key because is many json key and is array value of json key. After that i'm wanna parse value of filter and group from value many json key.

Thanks

Comment: What is the expected output based on the above code example? All the keys?

Comment: i'm wanna parse `{
            "filter": [
                {"a": "a"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "group": [
                {"a": "a"}
            ]
        } ` from all json key after that i'm parse again value of `filter` and `group`

Comment: i'm try like this `var body = request.body;var keys = Object.keys(body);for(var i = 0;i < keys.length; i++){var c = Object.values(body[keys[i]]);console.log(c);
 }`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```
Object.entries(json).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc.filter.push(...value[0].filter);
  acc.group.push(...value[1].group);
  return acc;
}, {filter: [], group: []})
```

Based on your compiler options, this should do the trick:

```
const res = Object.entries(json).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc.filter = acc.filter.concat(value[0].filter);
  acc.group = acc.group.concat(value[1].group);
  return acc;
}, {filter: <any>[], group: <any>[]});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06hrqa9j/)

Comment: Thank is work, i'm using typescript but when the `var body = request.body; Object.enteries(body)..` i'm got warning `Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.` the warning from `acc.filter.push(...value[0].filter);` and `acc.group.push(...value[1].group);`

Comment: Try to change the last row to `{filter: <any>[], group: <any>[]}`

Comment: Like this `...{filter: <any>[], group: <any>[]});` ? And i'm got warning `Object is of type 'unknown'` from `acc.filter.push(...value[0].filter);` and `acc.group.push(...value[1].group);`

Comment: Not sure what compiler options you're using, is there an online platform that I can use to reproduce this?

Comment: try running using this, online typescript ide https://repl.it/repls/BouncyScientificGlitch

Comment: i'm using `esnext` target compiler and for module i'm using `commonjs` on my `tsconfig.json`

Comment: same warning `Object is of type 'unknown'` i'm got from `...value[0].filter` and `...value[1].group`. i'm think because error from `...[key, value]` i'm check `var key: unknown` and  `var value: unknown`

Comment: See my updated answer, the spread operator is not supported under your configuration

Comment: i'm got same warning from your updated answer, i'm think error from variable type on `...[key, value]` i'm chek the variable of `key` and `value` from `...[key, value]` is `unknown` type variable